# Haskell: interaction between withCurrentDirectory and runConcurrently

Tags: haskell, concurrency, scripting

I'm trying to automate some file management in Haskell using `System.Directory`. My script works synchronously, but in my use case, I have about twenty directories, for each of which I'd like to start a long-running process, so I am also using `Control.Concurrent.Async`, which seems to be causing problems.

Minimal Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-10.3 --install-ghc runghc --package async

import Control.Concurrent.Async (Concurrently(..), runConcurrently)
import Control.Monad (filterM)
import System.Directory as Dir
import System.Process (callCommand)

dirs :: IO [FilePath]
dirs = do
  prefix <- (++ "/Desktop/dirs/") <$> Dir.getHomeDirectory
  paths <- fmap (prefix ++) <$> Dir.listDirectory prefix
  filterM Dir.doesDirectoryExist paths

pullDir :: FilePath -> IO ()
pullDir dir = Dir.withCurrentDirectory dir $ callCommand "pwd"

main :: IO ()
main = dirs >>= runConcurrently . traverse (Concurrently . pullDir) >> pure ()
```

Expected output:

```
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/1
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/2
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/3
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/4
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/5
```

Actual output (varies!):

```
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/3
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/4
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/3
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/5
/Users/daniel/Desktop/dirs/5
```

We see the actual output runs `pwd` for the same directory more than once and fails to run `pwd` for some of the directories entierly. I'm almost positive this has to do with `withCurrentDirectory`.

How can I implement this correctly while still preserving the concurrency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with `withCurrentDirectory`. The current directory is a process-wide setting.  Whenever something changes it, it's changed for everything in the process.  This isn't a Haskell issue - it's just how the concept of "current directory" works.

To get this to work concurrently, you'll need to use full paths for everything, instead of changing the current directory.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. I guess my unix-foo could use some work.

I tried using full paths, but what ended up happening was the directory I ran the script from ended up with a mess of files lying around in it--files that I wanted to have in the subdirectories.

I think what I'll do is spin off a child process for each directory.